# Data disappears and pointer points to different object

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a quick sample program from a larger program I'm working on. This isn't perfect but it conveys the issue I'm having

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Node {
public: 
    vector<int> state;
    Node *parent; //Parent node

    //Initial Node
    Node(const vector<int> &s) : state(s) {}

    //Other Nodes
    Node(const vector<int> &state, Node &p) : state(state), parent(&p){ }
};

int main() {

    //Initial Node
    vector<int> initialState = { 1,2,3 };
    Node initialNode(initialState);

    vector<Node> listNodes;
    listNodes.push_back(initialNode);

    while (!listNodes.empty()) { //lisNodes[i].parent->state = {}; 2nd iteration
        Node node = listNodes.back(); //node.parent appears to point to node; 2nd iteration
        listNodes.erase(listNodes.begin());

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            vector<int> childState = { i+4,i+5,i+6 };
            Node childNode(childState, node);
            listNodes.push_back(childNode);
        } //Inside for loop lisNodes[i].parent->state = {i+4,i+5,i+6}

    } 

    return 0;

}
```

In the second iteration of the while loop, the state of the parents inside `listNodes` is empty

```
//lisNodes[i].parent->state = {}
```

Also, `parent` in `node` appears to point to itself during the second run instead of the actual parent node

I'm not sure why this is happening or a possible fix to it.

Comment: There's no  ̀second while loop` in the posted code.

Comment: second iteration I think...

Comment: edit to state second iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major problem is with

```
Node node = listNodes.back();
```

Here `node` is local to the while loop yet you store pointers to it.  When that node is destroyed at the end of the loop all of the pointers are now dangling.

Generally the fix would be to use

```
Node& node = listNodes.back();
```

So now you have a persistent object you can reference.  The issue with that though is you are modifying the vector with

```
listNodes.erase(listNodes.begin());
```

After that line all pointers and references to elements in the vector after the iterator are invalidated and `back()` gives you an element that will be invalidated.

You are going to either switch to a container where the references are not invalidated or find a different way to populate your tree structure.